# VBA Transfer of data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, userform

```
Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()

Load UserForm5

If TextBox1.Value = "" Or ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Incomplete Data", vbCritical, ""

Exit Sub
End If

UserForm5.TextBox1 = UserForm4.TextBox1.Value
UserForm5.TextBox2 = UserForm4.ComboBox1.Value

UserForm5.Show

End Sub
```

Note: When CommandButton11 is clicked (above - userform4), it opens below userform5. Userform5 textbox1 and textbox2 then retrieves data from sheet1 as shown in userform4 above.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

 Dim emptyRow As Long

 'Make Sheet 2 active
 Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

 'Determine emptyRow
 emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:G")) + 1

'Transfer information from userform fields to Sheet 2
 Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox1.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBox2.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TextBox3.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = TextBox4.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = TextBox5.Value

 End Sub
```

When Userform5 Commandbutton3 is clicked, I want the rows selected in sheet1 (i.e. based on the value from textbox1 which is pulled from sheet1) to be cut and pasted into sheet2

Hello All,

Hoping someone could help me out on this one. As the code shows above, I can get the values in the userform textbox to be added to sheet 2. The userform retrieves some of the records from sheet 1. What I am trying to achieve is when that value from sheet 1 is retrieved, I want to cut it from sheet 1 into sheet 2. What is the best way to do this?

Thank you

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: a straight answer would be: "use [`Cut()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cut) method fo `Range` object". But you could give more detail of your scenario

Comment: Hi DisplayName, basically the userform's TextBox1 and TextBox2 retrieves values from Sheet 1. The other textboxes, I type them in manually. When I click the command button, I also want the retrieved record from sheet 1 deleted and to go into sheet 2 with the extra values I typed in my userform

Comment: show the code that retrieves values from Sheet1

Comment: UserForm5.TextBox1 = UserForm4.TextBox1.Value
     UserForm5.TextBox2 = UserForm4.ComboBox1.Value

Comment: Still, we cannot see where’s your code retrieving values from Sheet1

Comment: @DisplayName. I have added the code in the post with explanation on how it works currently.

Comment: I cannot see any line pulling data from Sheet1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't the only way, but try an array. For more info see [VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

```
Dim rngOldRow, rngNewRow, arrValuesInRow

Set rngOldRow = Worksheets(1).Range("A10:N10") 'Defines the old row.
Set rngNewRow = Worksheets(2).Range("A5:N5") 'Defines the new row.

arrValuesInRow = rngOldRow 'Copies values to an array variable.

arrValuesInRow(1, 2) = TextBox1.Value 'Changes values in the array.
arrValuesInRow(1, 3) = TextBox2.Value
arrValuesInRow(1, 5) = TextBox3.Value
arrValuesInRow(1, 7) = TextBox4.Value
arrValuesInRow(1, 8) = TextBox5.Value

rngNewRow.Value = arrValuesInRow 'Copies from the array to Sheet 2.

rngOldRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp 'Deletes the row on Sheet 1.
```

Comment: Hi scenography, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, your script is not working for me. When my userform is executed, it is only the top row from sheet 1 that migrates to sheet 2.

Comment: @Kev, I changed the code to say rngNewRow instead of emptyRow. Also change the lines that define rngOldRow and rngNewRow. I can't tell from your code how to define the old row, but the new row can be `Set rngNewRow = Worksheets(2).Range("A:H").Rows(emptyRow)` (if columns A to H are correct).

Comment: @scenograpghy. Thanks that worked perfectly for me. Good stuff.